# How to automatically calculate monthly total for below image highlighted columns. Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to calculate net weight and released % monthly. its highlighted in the image attached.

[image]

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method.

1. Select the desired column. (Must hold the Ctrl button)
2. Insert a chart

[image: Chart]

Charts automatically checks and displays the data.

Or use this code in resulting cells

```
=SUMIF([Date col]؛[Join required]؛[C column or E column])
```

This code is placed in the cell J3

```
=SUMIF(A:A؛I3؛C:C)
```

Comment: I think question is about Net Weight and % against each month. How to calculate against each month. User has not asked about graph

Comment: They need an automated method for displaying data.
If you see a bit of the chart settings so that it's easier to calculate and display the data.
Which will need to be formulated.

Comment: Well! I am sure, but i think =sumif formula can be helpful here

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Create a pivot table and set the Net Weight and Released % as values while the date is the description. After that select one of the entries in the pivot table an select the option to group the values. Multi-Select the entry month and year and you should get a view that has the information you're looking for, even if it is slightly different from what your template. I'm not sure if pivot tables can be customized to have that layout.

More about the grouping can be found on [this official article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Group-items-in-a-PivotTable-report-059b7571-55a3-4127-8990-0cf0b9b880f7).